# Join two different tables ordered by common value (hotness)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select results from two different unrelated tables, `showcase` and `questions` to appear in a feed. They should be ordered by the common column `hotness` which is a float value.

```
SELECT s.id,s.date,s.title,s.views,s.image,s.hidpi,s.width,s.description,u.display_name,u.avatar
FROM showcase AS s
INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.user_id = u.id
UNION 
SELECT q.id,q.date,q.title,q.views,q.text,u.display_name,u.avatar,0,0,0
FROM questions AS q
INNER JOIN users AS u ON q.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY hotness DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I've tried `UNION`, but I have no idea how I should be using it here and get this error `unknown column hotness`

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that the column is unknown, because I see it nowhere in the query except in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yeah, no idea what to  do. It doesn't need to be selected though, just ordered by it.

Comment: is hotness in users or showcase tables? and even if it is... think about order of operations.  Query 1 results query 2 results, merge and get distinct values, then sort.  The engine has no ability to go back to the base tables to get hotness (assuming it's in one of the tables)

Comment: hotness is a column in `showcase` and `questions`.  if `showcase` has 2 rows, one has `hotness=10` another `hotness=1`, then `questions` has 2 rows, one with `hotness=9` another `hotness=5`, then the order should be showcase->question->question->showcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the value in order for the `ORDER BY` to recognize it:

```
SELECT s.id,s.date,s.title,s.views,s.image,s.hidpi,s.width,s.description,u.display_name,u.avatar, s.hotness
FROM showcase AS s
INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.user_id = u.id
UNION ALL
SELECT q.id,q.date,q.title,q.views,q.text,u.display_name,u.avatar,0,0,0, q.hotness
FROM questions AS q
INNER JOIN users AS u ON q.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY hotness DESC;
```

Note that I also changed the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  Unless you intend to remove duplicates, there is no reason to incur the extra processing for doing that.

Comment: That works, along with @metfan's answer. Which is better?? Although I don't understand his answer

Comment: @frosty . . . They are very similar.  In general in MySQL, you don't want to use subqueries in the `FROM` clause unless necessary, because MySQL materializes subqueries -- unnecessary overhead.  However, the `ORDER BY` also causes materialization, so not using subqueries in this case is just a (good) habit.  Also, the `UNION` versus `UNION ALL` is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT r.* FROM (
    SELECT s.id,s.date,s.title,s.views,s.image,s.hidpi,s.width,s.description,u.display_name,u.avatar, s.hotness
    FROM showcase AS s
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.user_id = u.id
    UNION 
    SELECT q.id,q.date,q.title,q.views,q.text,u.display_name,u.avatar,0,0,0, q.hotness
    FROM questions AS q
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON q.user_id = u.id 
) as r
ORDER BY r.hotness DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You need to merge Union result in subquery to apply Order by on the result. I also added hotness in select clause, please check I take field from good table.